# Your domain gmail.com is not allowed in header From

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, spf

1 month before this code is working fine on website which hosting is provided by "godaddy" now hosting is renew by different server "namecheap" after renewing domain this error is occur during sending mail.
I updated PHPMailer file but nothing happen.

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: phpmailerException

Message: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: abc@gmail.com: "Your IP: ***.***.**.** : Your domain gmail.com is not allowed in header From"

Filename: /Directory_path/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php

Line Number: 1585

Backtrace:

File: /Directory_path/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php
Line: 1337
Function: smtpSend

File: /home/Directory_path/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php
Line: 1215
Function: postSend

File: /Directory_path/views/contact.php
Line: 34
Function: send

File: /Directory_path/controllers/Contact.php
Line: 7
Function: view

```
$name= $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain_name.com";
$mail->port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = "info@example.com";
$mail->Password = '********';
$file_name = $_FILES["attc"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES["attc"]["tmp_name"];
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/views/upload_images/';
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$file_name);
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('abc@gmail.com','Mail Header');
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->isHTML(true);
if($file_name != '' && $file_name != null){
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/application/views/upload_images/".$file_name,$file_name);
}
$mail->Subject = "Info From Web";
$mail->Body = '<strong>' .$msg . '</strong><br><br><h3>Regard :  '.$name.'</h3>';
if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "<script>alert('Email Sent Success!')</script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script>alert('".$mail->ErrorInfo."')</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send from a gmail address without sending through a gmail server. This is forgery and will be blocked by google's SPF rules, as you're finding. If you want to send from a gmail address, you must send through a gmail server.

The real problem is that you are setting the from address to the submitter's address. Don't do that, as you'll have exactly the problems you're seeing. Put your own address in the from address, and put the submitter's address in a reply-to address. See [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) for how to do this.

Comment: I forgot to mention but i'm not using gmail address to send email i'm using domain mail to send emails.

Comment: If someone submits a gmail address, it will try to send from a gmail address. I don’t know what you mean by “domain mail”.. Also you’re mixing up security settings - tls mode will not work on port 465; either change to ssl mode or use port 587. The docs cover this extensively.